# Is there any real sense in uniform distributed partition keys for small applications using DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Amazon DynamoDB doc is focused on partition key uniform distribution is the most important point in creating correct db architecture.
From the other hand, when things come to real numbers, you can find that your app **will never go out of one partition**. That is, according to doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions
partition calculation formula is

```
( readCapacityUnits / 3,000 ) + ( writeCapacityUnits / 1,000 ) = initialPartitions (rounded up)
```

So you need more than 1000 writes per second demand (for 1 kb data) to go out from one partition. But according to my calculation for the most of small application you don't even need default 5 writes per second - 1 is enough. (To be precise you can go out of one partition if your data excesses 10Gb but it's also a big number).

The question becomes more important when you realize that creating of any additional indexes requires additional writes per second allocation.
Just imagine, I have some data related to particular user, for example, "posts".
I create "posts" data table and then according to Amazon guidelines I choose the next key format:

```
partition: id, // post id like uuid
sort: // don't need it
```

Since there is no any two posts having the same id we don't need sort key here. But then you realize that the most common operation you have is requesting a list of posts for a particular user. So you need to create secondary index like:

```
partition: userId,
sort: id // post id
```

But every secondary index requires additional read/write units so the cost of such decision is doubled!
From the other hand, keeping in mind that you have only one partition, you could already have such primary key:

```
partition: userId
sort: id // post id
```

That works fine for your purposes and doesn't double your cost.
So the question is: have I missed something? May be partition key is much more effective than sort one even inside one partition?

Addition: you may say "ok, now having userId as partition key for posts is ok but when you have 100000 users in your app you'll run into troubles with scaling". But in reality the trouble can be only for some "transition" case - when you have only a few partitions with a group of active users posts all in one partition and inactive ones in the other one. If you have thousands of users it's natural that you have a lot of users with active posts, the impact of one user is negligible and statistically their posts are evenly distributed between a lot of partitions due to big numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think its absolutely fine if you make sure you wont exceed partition limits by increasing `RCU/WCU` or by growth of your data. Moreover, [best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html) says

> If the table will fit entirely into a single partition (taking into consideration growth of your data over time), and if your application's read and write throughput requirements do not exceed the read and write capabilities of a single partition, then your application should not encounter any unexpected throttling as a result of partitioning.